# PHP cron job and php mail() function

Tags: php, cron

I have a simple PHP script in a directory beta/cron/cron.php to send out mail as follows:

```
<?php

$to = "me@email.com";
$subject = "test subject";
$message = "test message";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: me@email.com" . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo $result;

?>
```

If I got to this file in my browser everything works and the mail is sent/received.

However I want to set this up to run as a cron job but I get an error email instead from my hosts Cron Daemon address with the following:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.27
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

My cron job is as follows:

```
* * * * * php beta/cron cron.php
```

My hosting company is register365.com and I think the SMTP is set up correctly but cannot figure out if there are logs for this somewhere or what might be causing this issue.

Comment: Are `beta/cron` and `cron.php` absolute paths?

Comment: Add absolute paths in cron job

Comment: Sorry am more used to working in WAMP and haven't done much with CRON jobs on a live server before. When you say absolute path do you mean from the public_html directory? The full path to my file is public_html/beta/cron/cron.php

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FMK and @B.Desai,

changing it to public_html/beta/cron/cron.php worked